# ContourPlot of an Implicit Function with a parameter

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to use ContourPlot for an implicit function when another parameter is changing.

To be more precise, suppose we have a function of the form F[x,y,z]. Now for a fixed value of z=z1, we can use ContourPlot to plot the locus of points that satisfy F[x,y,z1]=0 by simply using

```
Contourplot[F[x,y,z1]==0,{x,xl,xh},{y,yl,yh}]
```

I wanted to see if there is a way to vary z1 and plot what happens.

Thanks

Ali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Manipulate`:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Cos[y + x^2 z]
Manipulate[ContourPlot[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}],
    {{z, 0}, -3, 3}]
```